# Partially expanding recursively expanded variables

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Consider the following makefile example:

```
all:;

varname := a

val = $($(varname)-value)

a-value := AAA
b-value := BBB

$(info val: $(val))
varname := b
$(info val: $(val))
```

As expected, running `make` on this makefile results in:

```
val: AAA
val: BBB
```

Since `val` is a [*recursively expanded* variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Flavors.html#Flavors), its expansion occurs when  referencing (i.e., `$(val)`).

At the moment of defining the variable `val`, the variable `a-value` is not defined yet. Therefore, defining `val` as a [*simply expanded* variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Flavors.html#Flavors) instead (i.e., with `:=` instead of `=`):

```
val := $($(varname)-value)
```

results in `$($(varname)-value)` being *immediately expanded* to an empty string, which, in turn, results in an empty `$(val)`.

I would like to know whether there is a way to *immediately* expand `varname` in `val`'s definition, but *defer* the expansion of the result until the moment in which `val` is *referenced*, as if `val` were actually defined in the makefile above as:

```
val = $(a-value)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could do this:

```
simplevar := $(varname)
val = $($(simplevar)-value)
```

Comment: So, the trick consists of creating an additional level of indirection when referencing, isn't it?

Comment: Sort of, although since `simplevar` is expanded immediately you're not really introducing another level of indirection.  More like you're splitting the indirection into two parts, so they can have different treatment.  Break out the part you want expanded immediately into a separate immediate variable.  Of course, there may be reasons that this doesn't work so well but those are not evident in your question.

Comment: [This tutorial](https://make.mad-scientist.net/evaluation-and-expansion/), which was written by you, is actually somewhat related to my question. In the section under the title **Expansion is Single-Pass**: *It’s important to understand that make will walk every string exactly one time during expansion. As it walks the string it will expand any macro reference it discovers (which may, itself, require further expansion), then continue.*

Comment: Thanks for the answer and further elaborating.